# Unable to access Streamlit container on container group via exposed port on Azure VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, streamlit

I'm attempting to access a Streamlit instance running on a container as part of the container group, via the Public IP address of a VM running on azure but I'm unable to do so (the page doesn't load). Ideally the streamlit page would load and then network with the other containers for some functionality installed on them - hence the container group. Currently the container group works when running locally, both in terms of streamlit working and interfacing with the other containers. The docker compose file is below (names have been changed):

```
services:
  container1:
    container_name: container1
    hostname: name1
    image: image1
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=***
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=***
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/

  container2:
    container_name: container2
    hostname: name2
    image: image2

  streamlit_container:
    container_name: streamlit_container
    hostname: streamlit_name 
    image: streamlit_image
    ports:
      - 81:8501
         
  container3:
    container_name: container3
    hostname: name3
    image: image3
    environment:
      - ATS_USE_GPU=1
      - SA_USE_GPU=1
    volumes:
      - /static/models:/summariser/ats_sa/models:ro
    runtime: nvidia
```

For reference, the streamlit container's dockerfile is below as well:

```
WORKDIR /streamlit

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /pages ./pages
COPY main_page.py main_page.py
COPY get_text.py get_text.py

EXPOSE 8501

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "main_page.py"]
```

Furthermore, all network traffic into the VM has been enabled while I try and figure this out.

So far I've tried the following:

1. Testing the VM's accessibility via public IP on port 80 with Nginx (this works)
2. Adding the `network_mode: "host"` tag to the container running streamlit - this allows me to access the streamlit page but it doesn't interface with the others in the container group.